# Using Apache Camel ProducerTemplate to send JSON message to ActiveMQ

Tags: apache-camel, activemq-classic

I have a camel route setup like the following to send a java object to an activemq queue.

```
from("direct:clientRequest")
.marshal().json(JsonLibrary.Jackson)
.to("activemq:queue:command");
```

I want to do the following:

1. Map the "clientRequest" uri to some Java method
2. Use ProducerTemplate's "sendBody" method to send a JSON form of a Java object to the activemq queue.

Is this possible?

I am asking this question after a lot of homework. Please suggest a way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use pojo producing in Apache Camel. See this page for more details

- http://camel.apache.org/pojo-producing.html

And there is an example that shows more about using pojo producing/consuming in Camel

- http://camel.apache.org/pojo-messaging-example.html